# Exclude dynamic dependencies from build command?

Tags: linux, gcc, ld, ldd

Let's suppose we have a library libutils.so:

```
ldd libutils.so
...
libdependency.so
...
```

Let's further suppose that we need to build an application:

```
g++ appliation.cpp -lutils -o application
```

May we omit -ldependency in the above command or must we write:

```
g++ appliation.cpp -lutils -ldependency -o application
```

Answer (score 2):

> May we omit -ldependency in the above command

If you control the linkage of `libutils.so` itself, yes you can. An illustration:

**main.c**

```
extern void foo(void);

int main(void)
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

**foo.c**

```
extern void bar(void);

void foo(void)
{
    bar();
}
```

**bar.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

We'll make a program that depends on `libfoo.so`, which depends on `libbar.so`.
Make the object files:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c -fPIC foo.c bar.c
gcc -Wall -c main.c
```

Now link `libbar.so` the No Frills way:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libbar.so bar.o
```

Next link `libfoo.so` like this:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o -L. -lbar -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
```

The effect of the [`-rpath linker option`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html) is:

> -rpath=dir
>
> Add a directory to the runtime library search path. This is used when linking an ELF executable with shared objects.
>   All -rpath arguments are concatenated and passed to the runtime linker, which uses them to locate shared objects at runtime.
>   The -rpath option is also used when locating shared objects which are needed by shared objects explicitly included in the link;
>   see the description of the -rpath-link option. If -rpath is not used when linking an ELF executable,
>   the contents of the environment variable LD_RUN_PATH will be used if it is defined.

The result is that:

```
$ objdump -x -j .dynamic libfoo.so | egrep '(RUNPATH|NEEDED)'
  NEEDED               libbar.so
  RUNPATH              /home/imk/develop/so/scrap
```

`libfoo.so` has a `NEEDED` entry inscribed in its `.dynamic` section saying that
the library has a runtime dependency on `libbar.so`. Likewise it has
a `RUNPATH` entry there saying that runtime dependencies may be searched for in `/home/imk/develop/so/scrap`
That's just the `pwd` where I did the linkage: it doesn't have to be that, as long as is indeed
a directory where `libbar.so` can be found when the linker or loader comes looking for it.

This information can be read by the linker, when `libbar.so` is linked with something else,
and by the loader at runtime. So finally I can link `prog` like this:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoo -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
```

I don't need to mention `-lbar`, because `libfoo.so` itself provides the linker with
the information that `libfoo.so` depends on `libbar.so`, and where to look for it.

Since I also passed `-rpath=$(pwd)` in the linkage of `prog`, we see that prog
will provide *this* information

```
$ objdump -x -j .dynamic prog | egrep '(RUNPATH|NEEDED)'
  NEEDED               libfoo.so
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
  RUNPATH              /home/imk/develop/so/scrap
```

to the runtime loader: `prog` needs `libfoo.so`, and it can be looked for
in `/home/imk/develop/so/scrap`. When the loader finds `libfoo.so` and loads it, it will
discover from it that:

```
  NEEDED               libbar.so
  RUNPATH              /home/imk/develop/so/scrap
```

and will in turn find and load `libbar.so`, which will enable it to resolve all
symbols referred to in the process under construction. Consequently, `prog` can be run immediately:

```
$ ./prog
bar
```

I didn't *have* to pass `-rpath=$(pwd)` in the linkage of `prog`. But if I hadn't:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoo
$ ./prog
./prog: error while loading shared libraries: libfoo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

the loader wouldn't know where to find `libfoo.so`. See:

```
$ ldd prog
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffffcc35000)
    libfoo.so => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4d1aff9000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4d1b5ec000)
```

And then I'd have to resort to:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
$ ldd prog
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff964dc000)
    libfoo.so => ./libfoo.so (0x00007fc2a7f35000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc2a7b44000)
    libbar.so => ./libbar.so (0x00007fc2a7942000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc2a8339000)    
$ ./prog
bar
```

**Later**

> it is still a little bit unclear whether the presence of libdependency.so among the output of ldd libutils.so is enough to omit -ldependencny during linkage

You would need to ask at least one and at most two questions about the output of `ldd utils.so`:-

1. Does the `ldd libutils.so` output report the so-name `libdependency.so` *at all*?
2. If Yes to **1**, does it also resolve that so-name to an actual file?

If No to **1** then `libdutils.so` contains no informatation about its dependency of `libdependency.so`
and you *must* specify `-lutils -ldependency` in any further linkage.

If Yes to **1** but No to **2** (i.e.`ldd libutils.so` reports `libdependency.so => not found`) then `libutils.so` has
a `NEEDED` entry for the so-name `libdependency.so` but *not* a `RUNPATH` entry by which the linker or
loader can resolve that so-name to any actual file. In that case again, you must link `-lutils -ldependency` if you link `-lutils`, so that the linker will *then* search for a file that resolves `-ldependency`. At least, you must do so as long as `ldd libutils.so` *still* reports `libdependency.so => not found` when you do the linkage. Read on...

If Yes to **1** and Yes to **2** then you can drop `-ldependency` in a further linkage *provided it is
run in the same environment in which you ran* `ldd libutils.so`

That caveat is needed because if `ldd libutils.so` resolves `libdependency.so`, all you know
is that `ldd` was able to resolve `libdependency.so` using the loader's search algorithm:-

- The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (in the active shell), lists a directory
  in which `libdependency.so` is found, or
- `libutils.so` provides a `RUNPATH` in which `libdependency.so` is found, or
- `libdependency.so` is found in one of the directories listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or the recursive `include`-expansion thereof), or
- `libdependency.so` is found in one of the loader's *trusted* search directories, `/lib` and `/usr/lib`

If `ldd` can resolve `libdependency.so` in one of those four ways, then the linker will be able
to do it the same way, *as long as that way still succeeds when you do the linkage*.

So going back to my example, and my linkage:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o -L. -lbar -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
```

After that, thanks to `-rpath=$(pwd)`. I can link `prog` like:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoo
```

without mentioning `-lbar`, and it succeeds. Now I link `libfoo.so` instead *without*
an `-rpath`:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o -L. -lbar
```

after which:

```
$ objdump -x -j .dynamic libfoo.so | egrep '(RUNPATH|NEEDED)'
  NEEDED               libbar.so
```

there's no `RUNPATH` anymore, and consequently:

```
$ ldd libfoo.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffda05e6000)
    libbar.so => not found
```

because the loader can't resolve `libbar.so` in any other way either.

Now I can no longer link `prog` without `-lbar`:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoo
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libbar.so, needed by ./libfoo.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
./libfoo.so: undefined reference to `bar'
```

But if I do:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd)
```

then:

```
$ ldd libfoo.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe56d1e000)
    libbar.so => /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/libbar.so (0x00007fd2456e8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd2452f7000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd245aec000)
```

`libfoo.so`'s dependency `libbar.so` is resolved by the loader, using the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and in the
same way by the linker:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoo; echo Done
Done
```

And if I clear `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` again:

```
$ unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lfoo; echo Done
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libbar.so, needed by ./libfoo.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
./libfoo.so: undefined reference to `bar'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Done
```

back to failure.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is very detailed. But it is still a little bit unclear whether the presence of libdependecy.so among the output of ldd libutils.so is enough to omit -ldependecny during linkage. Is it enough for the linker to search for this library and report an error if it can not find it?

Comment: @Alexey See extended answer.